# Create a custom collection from a PHP array

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a collection in laravel that contains the Companies (as key) and values - the names of the departments from a json.

The json file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": test@test,
        "company": "Company 1",
        "department": "Department 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "email": test@test,
        "company": "Company 2",
        "department": "Department 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "email": test@test,
        "company": "Company 3",
        "department": "Department 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "email": test@test,
        "company": "Company 1",
        "department": "Department 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "email": test@test,
        "company": "Company 2",
        "department": "Department 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "email": test@test,
        "company": "Company 3",
        "department": "Department 2"
    }
]
```

The `$jsonData` is the php array from json (json_encode)

This is how I tried ...

```
$dataCollection = collect($jsonData)->map(fn($item) => [
    'Company' => $item['Company'],
    'Department' => $item['Department'],
])->unique()->groupBy('Company');
```

It return this:

```
"Company 1" => [
   ['Company' => 'Company 1','Department' => 'Department 1'],
   ['Company' => 'Company 1','Department' => 'Department 2']
],
...
```

How can I get only the names for the Departments in the Company group like this:

```
"Company 1" => [
    'Department 1',
    'Department 2',
],
```

Comment: use instead mapWithKeys  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys

Comment: It return an array with key the company name and value "string" department name (probably first) ... not an array of department names

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataCollection = collect(json_decode($jsonData,false))
  ->mapToGroups(function($item) {
    return [$item->company => $item->department];
  })->toArray();
```

Comment: but how can I make them unique (departments) ? It push all the departments on the company but there are duplicates...

Comment: Is that a new question?  There are no duplicate departments in your sample data